# cbind nested list into data.frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` that contains multiple columns. Some columns are nested lists with a size of `N x K`, where `K` is the number of columns, and `N` is the number of rows of a particular nested list. An example of such a list is provided below:

```
df = list(structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(kodJezyka = "RPd008|ang", kodStopniaZnajomosciWPismie = "RPs001|B2", 
        kodStopniaZnajomosciWMowie = "RPs001|B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(kodJezyka = c("RPd008|ang", "RPd008|ros"), 
        kodStopniaZnajomosciWPismie = c("RPs001|C1", "RPs001|C2"
        ), kodStopniaZnajomosciWMowie = c("RPs001|C1", "RPs001|C1"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

Some of the cells/objects/elements of lists have more than 1 row (`df[[5]]`). I want to convert each of such lists into columns and combine them with data.frame without dropping empty elements (`character(0)`) and taking into account the id of an object/cell. Like this:

```
df = lapply(1:length(df), function(x){
  if(is_empty(df[[x]])){
    data.frame(id = x)
  } else {  
    df[[x]] %>% data.frame() %>% mutate(id = x) %>% select(id, everything())  
  }
  }) %>% rbindlist(., fill = T)
```

But as ID I want to use the existing column and combine the output with the main data.frame. Representative example as follows:

```
structure(list(id = c("c44ba05895b9b7d08b4f101d16b1ff79", "657874a7a8c1d209456c2a0891dcdbab", 
"3d96992ba5c44283c11cf762155a5fd4", "127c1451cdb3f03d63e3ba2c7d81b2a8", 
"9a3f55f9ef216f0a33c8f6db67313d2a", "e4e3f166fa8a39096e2900f7a968649c"
), statusOferty = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), typOferty = c("OFERTA_PRACY", 
"OFERTA_PRACY", "OFERTA_PRACY", "OFERTA_PRACY", "OFERTA_PRACY", 
"OFERTA_PRACY"), wymagania.wymaganiaKonieczne.jezykiSzczegoly = list(
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(kodJezyka = "RPd008|ang", kodStopniaZnajomosciWPismie = "RPs001|B2", 
        kodStopniaZnajomosciWMowie = "RPs001|B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(kodJezyka = c("RPd008|ang", "RPd008|ros"), 
        kodStopniaZnajomosciWPismie = c("RPs001|C1", "RPs001|C2"
        ), kodStopniaZnajomosciWMowie = c("RPs001|C1", "RPs001|C1"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    wymagania.wymaganiaDodatkowe.jezyki = list(character(0), 
        character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
        character(0)), warunkiPracyIPlacy.kodTrybuPracy = list(
        character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
        "RPd110|2", character(0))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Would appreciate any help and/or suggestions.

Comment: What should we do when a list inside a column of your "main" data frame contains a data frame that has more rows than the main data frame? In other words, lists are capable of storing objects of different length. Data frames instead cannot deal with columns of different length. It might be more appropriate to continue with a list format.

Comment: The starting point is a structure to which you have assigned a class to which it does not conform with regard to basic features expected by functions designed to be used on that class. However, you can run `as.data.frame(df)` and may get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Appears that as.data.frame provide a mechanism for rectifying the flaws in that structure:

```
as.data.frame(df)
#------------------------------
                                id statusOferty    typOferty
1 c44ba05895b9b7d08b4f101d16b1ff79            A OFERTA_PRACY
2 657874a7a8c1d209456c2a0891dcdbab            A OFERTA_PRACY
3 3d96992ba5c44283c11cf762155a5fd4            A OFERTA_PRACY
4 127c1451cdb3f03d63e3ba2c7d81b2a8            A OFERTA_PRACY
5 9a3f55f9ef216f0a33c8f6db67313d2a            A OFERTA_PRACY
6 e4e3f166fa8a39096e2900f7a968649c            A OFERTA_PRACY
                        wymagania.wymaganiaKonieczne.jezykiSzczegoly wymagania.wymaganiaDodatkowe.jezyki
1                                                               NULL                                    
2                                                               NULL                                    
3                                   RPd008|ang, RPs001|B2, RPs001|B2                                    
4                                                               NULL                                    
5 RPd008|ang, RPd008|ros, RPs001|C1, RPs001|C2, RPs001|C1, RPs001|C1                                    
6                                                               NULL                                    
  warunkiPracyIPlacy.kodTrybuPracy
1                                 
2                                 
3                                 
4                                 
5                         RPd110|2
6
```

Furthermore I get `[1] TRUE` for a test with `identical`.